# context is not iterable TypeError: context is not iterable ,Getting this error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

i was just following a react course about Context API i don't know if they have introduced any new syntax?if so please do say
the error is "context is not iterable TypeError: context is not iterable"

Here is the app.js:---

just imported react router and the context function(NoteState)

```
import './App.css';
import About from "./components/About"
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar"
import Home from "./components/Home"
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route

} from "react-router-dom";
import NoteState from './context/notes/NoteState';


function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <NoteState>
        <Router>
          <Navbar title="InoteBook"/>
          <div className="container">
         <Routes>
          <Route path="/about" element={<About/>}/>
            
          <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
            
        </Routes>
        </div>
       </Router>
       </NoteState>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

here is the notecontext:--

pretty simple just creating a new context and exporting it

```
import { createContext } from "react";

const noteContext = createContext();

export default noteContext;
```

Here is the main NoteState file:---

just hard coded some notes from my mongodb document and used it as the context

```
import { useState } from "react";
import NoteContext from "./notecontext";

const NoteState = (props)=>{
    const notesInitial =[{
            "_id": "6470a303fca0259ac90f3bbd",
            "user": "646b656de67a029e93797b15",
            "title": "binod",
            "description": "binod binod binod",
            "tag": "binod",
            "date": "2023-05-26T12:16:03.400Z",
            "__v": 0
          },
          {
            "_id": "6470a31efca0259ac90f3bbf",
            "user": "646b656de67a029e93797b15",
            "title": "binodbinodbinod",
            "description": "binod binod binod binod binod",
            "tag": "binod binod binod",
            "date": "2023-05-26T12:16:30.130Z",
            "__v": 0
          }]
          const [notes,setNotes] = useState(notesInitial)
    return(
        <NoteContext.Provider value={{notes, setNotes}}>
            {props.children}
        </NoteContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default NoteState
```

here is the Home.js component:---

main parts have arrows at the beginning

```
import React from "react";
import noteContext from "../context/notes/notecontext";
import { useContext } from "react";

const Home = (props) => {
>  const context = useContext(noteContext)
>  const [notes,setNotes] = context
  return (
    

    <>
      <div className="container my-3">
        <h2>Add a note</h2>
        <form className="my-3">
          <div className="mb-3">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1" className="form-label">
              Email address
            </label>
            <input
              type="email"
              className="form-control"
              id="exampleInputEmail1"
              aria-describedby="emailHelp"
            />
            <div id="emailHelp" className="form-text">
              We'll never share your email with anyone else.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1" className="form-label">
              Password
            </label>
            <input
              type="password"
              className="form-control"
              id="exampleInputPassword1"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="mb-3 form-check">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              className="form-check-input"
              id="exampleCheck1"
            />
            <label className="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">
              Check me out
            </label>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
      
> <div className="container my-3">
>         <h2>Your Notes</h2>
> 
>         {notes.map((note)=>{
> return(note.title) 
>         })}
>       </div>*
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with `const [notes,setNotes] = context`. Here you're using array destructuring syntax on `context` which is an object, which by default aren't iterable so the syntax throws an error. For object destructuring, you need to destructure your object properties like so:

```js
const {notes,setNotes} = context;
```

Alternatively,  you can pass an array to your provider instead:

```js
<NoteContext.Provider value={[notes, setNotes]}>
```

As arrays are iterable, the destructuring syntax that you had originally with `[` and `]` will work in this case.

---

As a side note, you might want to memoize your context value to avoid recreating it on every rerender, and instead only create a new object/array when needed. Below is an example for creating an object:

```js
const memoizedValue = useMemo(() => ({notes, setNotes}), [notes]); // when notes changes create a new object with the new note
<NoteContext.Provider value={memoizedValue}>
```

Above we're passing `notes` as a dependency to useMemo() as we want a new object to be created when `notes` changes. As `setNotes` is coming from `useState()`, it has a stable-identity, meaning that it's reference will remain the same through all renders of your app, so there is no need to pass that as a dependency (passing it won't hurt either though).